# Override the Cartthrob license key generation process

Tags: cartthrob

Is there a way to override the Cartthrob license key generation process?  Currently Cartthrob just defaults to a UUID, but we have a more in-depth license generation process that is required for our project.  I can probably hook into `cartthrob_on_authorize`, but am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to override the built-in key generation. I would recommend turning it off in the settings (by leaving the License Number field mapping empty in the Purchased Items channel). And then using the `cartthrob_on_authorize` hook.

```
foreach (ee()->cartthrob->cart->order('purchased_items') as $entry_id) {
    // generate your own license key
    //$key = ?

    // save the key to the DB, where XXX is your Purchased Items' license number field ID
    ee()->db->update('channel_data', array('field_id_XXX' => $key), array('entry_id' => $entry_id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, much appreciated.  This is the route I ended up taking.

Answer (score 0):

No I think creating your extension and hooking that event is the right way forward. This sort of thing is why they put hooks in there after all, do you think that hook will be too late, i.e. after UUID generation?